# What ASP.NET Web Controls implement IPostBackDataHandler?

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

Could someone point me to a list of controls that implement `IPostBackDataHandler`?

I want to know what controls implement this interface and what properties the controls will set during the `Postback`.

For example:

> Textbox : Text
>
> DropDownList : SelectedIndex

I'm basically looking for a list of properties that will not be saved in `ViewState`.

Thanks!

Comment: use MSDN or .net reflector or make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET IDE open the Object Browser Window. You can find this window on the View menu, or it may be, depending on your configuration, on the top toolbar.

In the search textbox type in the class, or interface in this case, you are looking for: `IPostBackDataHandler` and submit.

In the results, expand the type and then expand the derived types folder, you will find what you seek!

Answer (score 0):

this is what @TheZenker, is talking about...

[image]

Comment: @StackOverflow this answer is not a different one from TheZenker, here i am just providing a visual image, as a second answer, since i couldnt provide this(image) as a comment....